# Searching for VB Readkey

Tags: vb.net

I want to read a key for giving out some Text in a console. Example: If User pressed (KEY_XY), then run code : Console.WriteLine(EXAMPLE). Can someone help me?

Comment: [Ask] and the [tour] can help you write better posts, ask better questions, get better answers, get better grades and get fewer downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, try :

```
  Private Sub Myform_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.N AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control) Then 'note that here i'm using a modifier which means the code will be triggered if a user presses Ctrl+N, u can replace/edit it the way you want
        'whatever that you want
    End If
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a console application.

Comment: whatever, just use this code,it'll work..and make sure to mark it as answer

Comment: So, it did not work for me. I think that only works in forms applications